# Need to get the data of a second line of a shell output and add it to another shell input command using .format Python 2.6.6

Tags: python, shell, format

Below is the program for which I need to take the data from the second line of a shell output and put it in another shell command. I want to know how can I put the whole second line data into another command.

The output of first shell command i.e init is below

**3467788999987**

**1007457889308**

I have to put only '1007457889308' in the second command i.e in listlogins. Iam thinking something I can put in the question mark to get the second line data.Anything in format function to goto a particular line and get the data of the line?

```
init = "symaccess -sid 456 show {0} -type init | grep \"WWN\"".format(WWNname)
print init
logins = os.popen(init).read()
Initiator = logins.replace('       WWN  : ', '')
print Initiator
listlogins = "symaccess -sid 781 list logins -wwn {0}".format(Initiator[??0:17])
Insert = os.popen(listlogins).read()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is preferable to use `subprocess.Popen()` rather than `os.popen()` when running a subprocess. Also, when running `subprocess.Popen()` it is better to *not* use the option `shell=True`. The drawback of that is that it is not possible to "stack" commands with using a pipe (`|`). In the current example that is not a big issue, though, since the `grep` functionality can be easily implemented in pure Python code. Taken together, this allows for a solution similar to the following:

```
import subprocess

WWNname = 'something'
init_command = ['symaccess', '-sid', '456', 'show', WWNname, '-type' 'init']
init_output = subprocess.Popen(init_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
# In Python 2.7 we could do the following instead:
# init_output = subprocess.check_output(command_line)

initiators = []
for line in init_output.split('\n'):
    if 'WWN:' in line: 
        initiators.append(line.replace('WWN:','')

list_command = ['symaccess', '-sid', '781', 'list', 'logins', '-wwn', initators[-1]]
list_output = subprocess.Popen(list_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

This is not exactly the same, but as far as I can understand, it will produce the same result. Note that with this approach, it is possible to pick whichever WWNnumber one needs, by element addressing into the `initiators` list. Specifically, `iniators[-1]` will pick the last (i.e., the second) element of the list.

Comment: Thank you for the help. here Initiator[-1] is giving only the last digit of 1007457889308 which is 8 but if i want the entire number i.e  - 1007457889308 what should i input instead of -1.

Comment: `initiators[-1]` should give you the last list entry and each entry should contain multiple characters (digits). It seems very strange that you only get the very last digit if you use my suggested code. However, in your own solution `Initator[-1]` will only give the last digit, since that is not a list of strings but just a single string. If you want the last 13 characters, (corresponding to the whole number, you could do `Initator[-13:]` but that is a less robust solution as it requires the number to be exactly 13 digits long.

Comment: You can get `subprocess.Popen()` to work with a pipe if you set `shell=True` and pass in a string, rather than a list as command to execute. Otherwise it is possible to have Python run different subprocesses and manage the pipe, by setting `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and read the input. Please consult the documentation, https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html to get a deeper understanding.